# IntelliJ Pointer Selector Doesn't allow to Delete lines

Tags: intellij-idea, interface, keymapping

On IntelliJ 14 whenever I select some code then I cannot delete it, it removes that part of the selection. It must be related to the pointer which shows as a block but I don't know how to correct it. It displays:
[image]

My keymap is MacOsX.

How can I get the normal pointer bar and select text normally?

Comment: Do you have the IdeaVIM plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the Vim Emulator activated (Tools, Vim Emulator).